# How to change the "Ex libris" (from books) used in books to get the meaning "from diaries"?

Tags: vocabulary, meaning, english-to-latin-translation

I do not know any Latin at all. Could you please help me to solve the following problem?
I am wondering what would be a correct equivalent for "ex libris" used in books to change the meaning from "from books" to "from diaries" or "from calendars" ? Something like "Ex diariis"?

Answer (score 3):

*Ex diariis* is correct, although *diarium* usually means "daily ration/allowance" and seems to have been used in the sense of a "diary" only rarely.

A more classical expression for "diary, journal" may be *commentarii diurni* (daily notebook), so you could say: *ex commentariis diurnis* (or *diurnis commentariis*, whichever you prefer).

Comment: How about dropping *diurnis* and going with *e(x) commentariis* alone?

Comment: @JoonasIlmavirta That sounds like a good expression, depending on context, but since the question specifically asks for *diaries*, I think just *commentarii* alone would not be unambiguous.

Comment: I agree, it would be ambiguous. It depends on context whether it would hurt, but to me *commentarii* is not far from a diary.